# Django Model Error #E007: Why can't a database field be accessed directly and re-used as a foreign key pointer?

Tags: django, django-models

I believe the following used to be allowed but at 1.7 the System Check Framework returns the:

> models.E007 error

Let's say I have two models, Foo and Bar. Foo has a value `bar_id` which unsurprisingly represents `Bar's primary key`, allowing me to build a ForeignKey relation from `Foo` to `Bar`. So this works just fine:

```
from django.db import models

class Bar(models.Model):
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  blah = models.TextField()

class Foo:
  asdf = models.TextField()
  bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, db_column='bar_id' to_field='id')
```

But, if I want to access the value of `bar_id` directly within `Foo` AND use it to point to `Bar`, I can no longer do so:

```
from django.db import models

class Bar(models.Model):
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  blah = models.TextField()

class Foo:
  asdf = models.TextField()
  bar_value = models.IntegerField(db_column='bar_id')
  bar_fk = models.ForeignKey(Bar, db_column='bar_id' to_field='id')
```

Prior to 1.7 I'm pretty sure this worked just fine. Upon upgrading to 1.7 it brakes my app with the

> models.E007 error.
>   Foo: (models.E007) Field 'bar_fk' has column name 'bar_value' that is
>   used by another field.  HINT:  Specifiy a 'db_column' for the field

Well, the hint does no good as you can see that the db_column value is indeed already set.

Yes, I could refactor my code to replace instances of `Foo.bar_value` with `Foo.bar_fk.id`; and maybe I could even do something like this

```
class Foo:
  asdf = models.TextField()
  bar_fk = models.ForeignKey(Bar, db_column='bar_id' to_field='id')
  @property
  def bar_value(self):
    return self.bar_fk.id
```

But both of those involve the (database) expense of querying the foreign table simply to return a value that is already native in `Foo`?  I could certainly duplicate the field within the database, but that would be a crime against nature.

And if it indeed worked at 1.6, is there an underlying reason that it does not at 1.7?  Or is the `models.E007 error` itself giving a false-positive?

Thanks in advance.

Steve Walker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this worked fine in 1.6

-and-

because my production environment works fine in 1.7 regardless of the error message

-therefore-

I have concluded that I can suppress this error.

In settings.py:

SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ['models.E007',]

see:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS

I continue to believe the error itself is a false positive.

-Steve

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether your approach was valid before 1.7, but it looks very unusual. It's not clear to me why you want to define a field `bar_value`.

The usual approach would be to use

```
bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, db_column='bar_id' to_field='id')
```

Note that `db_column` and `to_field` are not necessary here, because you are using the defaults.

Then you would access the related instance and the value as follows:

- `foo.bar` returns a `Bar` instance (requiring a lookup)
- `foo.bar_id` returns the value of the id, no lookup required.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. have verified that it indeed is acceptable at 1.6; The use case here is that the field in question, 'bar_id' in this case,  has inherent value in and of itself,

Comment: [ed note: oops partial comment above] I did overlook the ability to access the underlying value by tacking the '_id' onto the end of the foreign key field name (thanks) But my oversimplified model above doesn't make the issue clear (It's a coincidence that I named my field 'bar_id' allowing the 'bar_id' FK naming convention to look exactly like what I wanted.  If instead of 'bar_id' being the field name, it was 'bar_booger', then I can certainly get the value of bar_booger by specifying foo.bar_id,  but what I can no longer do is specify foo.bar_booger directly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. You can always access the underlying value by appending `_id`. I don't see why it's important to be able to specify the name that you access this value with.  I think that allowing multiple fields to reference the same column as you were doing seems fragile. If you set `foo.bar_value` in Django 1.6, then presumably `foo.bar` is not automatically updated.